# why my Selection sort faster than Insertion sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Selection sort

```
public class Selection implements Sortable {
    public void sort(Comparable[] a){
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            int min=i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
                if(less(a[j],a[min])){
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            exch(a,i,min);
        }
    }

    private boolean less(Comparable v,Comparable w){
        return v.compareTo(w) <0;
    }

    private void exch(Comparable[] a,int i,int j){
        Comparable temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Insertion sort

```
public class Insertion implements Sortable{
    public void sort(Comparable[] a){

        for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=i;j>0;j--){
                if(less(a[j],a[j-1])){
                    exch(a,j,j-1);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and here is my compare time code.

```
public class SortCompare {

    public static double time(Sortable s,Comparable[] a){
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        s.sort(a);
        return timer.elapsedTime();
    }

    public static double timeRandomInput(Sortable s,int N,int T){
        double total = 0.0;
        Double[] a = new Double[N];
        for (int t=0;t<T;t++){
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                a[i]= StdRandom.uniform()*10;  //get a random number
            }
            total+=time(s,a);
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

main code

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Selection s = new Selection();
        Insertion i = new Insertion();
        //ShellSort sh =new ShellSort();
        double timeSelection = SortCompare.timeRandomInput(s,2000,100);
        double timeInsertion = SortCompare.timeRandomInput(i,2000,100);
        //double timeSh = SortCompare.timeRandomInput(sh,2000,100);
        System.out.println(timeSelection+" "+timeInsertion);
    }
}
```

The results surprised me. I have run so many times.My selection sort always faster than Insertion sort.I also check my code many times.I do not know where is probelm.

```
0.43200000000000033 0.9880000000000007
```

if I change the dataset to 10000.the Selection alomost 1 times faster than Insertion .

```
8.276999999999997 17.585000000000008
```

I am reading the book [algorithm 4th](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X). the writer said ,in the average case,Insertion sort will faster than Selection sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps because the implementation of Insertion Sort there is not that good. It can be written with "lots of swaps", as you did. It is commonly found in that form in textbooks, but not in real life - a nice implementation would "move" the elements (not swap them) and then poke the added element into the newly open position only at the end of that loop (instead of making the added element "walk through" the array). This saves about half the moves, and the repeated access into the array for the comparison just to get the same item every time (and therefore in Java, also many bounds checks).

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, both insertion sort and selection sort have an asymptotic running time of O(n^2).

So I'm not sure why you expect one to be faster than the other.

Also, the dataset that you're testing with is quite small. If you use a bigger dataset I would expect the running times to relatively grow closer together.

Comment: even if I change the dataset to 10000.the Selection alomost 1 times faster than Insertion .

Comment: I would still consider 10,000 a small dataset. And when talking about running time, 1 algorithm being twice as fast as another is not a lot. You would actually say their running time is similar. If for example, one algorithm was O(N) and another O(N^2), trying a dataset that was 5 times as big, should give a difference in running time of 5^2=25. In this case the difference stays the same (only twice as fast), which indicates that they have the same asymptotic running time.

Answer (score 0):

I make a stupid mistake here.

just change the code following.

```
public class Insertion implements Sortable{
    public void sort(Comparable[] a){

        for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=i;j>0;j--){
                if(less(a[j],a[j-1])){
                    exch(a,j,j-1);
                }
                else break;//i forget to add this line...
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 0.48000000000000037 0.43700000000000033.

Comment: Looks more reasonable, now if you also do the move instead of swap thing it should win by a decent margin